# SignInAsync works, but PasswordSignInAsync doesn't

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm creating a login and registration with Identity. Got a problem that when I register new account it logs in fine with SignInAsync, but when I try to log in from log in page with PasswordSignInAsync it doesn't succeed.

Here's my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegistrationViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new User
            {
                UserName = model.Username,
                Email = model.Email
            };

            if (_userManager != null)
            {
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                    return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
                }

                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                }
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Nepavyko prisijungti");

        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Maybe someone knows what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think `SignInAsync` issues an authentication cookie but delegates authentication process to another component (that you don't check in your code). so you might want to check if the credentials passed to `PasswordSignInAsync` are ok.

I mean, `SignInAsync` signs a user because it has been authenticated by other means. [PasswordSignInAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.passwordsigninasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_SignInManager_1_PasswordSignInAsync_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_) **attempts** to sign the requested user by using the Identity framework, matching the user with the provided password.

So the problem could be that the password is not correct, or is not properly issued to the server, or even the user does not exist...

Comment: Thank you for writing. The credentials seem to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

if they are configured, PasswordSignInAsync [does other checks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38537337/6396951) that SignInAsync doesn't do (like if the user is EmailConfirmed because the RequireConfirmedAccount option is set) and won't allow the user to log in if these checks don't pass